# Jetpack compose theme color not applied

Tags: android, themes, material3

I created to kt files MainActivity.kt and MainPage.kt, I pu my own colors in color.ket and refeerenced them in theme.kt

Omposables in MainActivity.kt get the right colors but MainPage.kt do not

I have a card in MainPage.kt:

Card(
colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
),
modifier = Modifier
.clip(cardShape)
.height(200.dp)
.width(cardWidth)
.border(
width = 3.dp,
color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
shape = cardShape
)
)
{
Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp, top=10.dp)) {
Text(text = "Info Card bottom")
}

MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary (material3) should be greenish, but it gives me light purple.

Any ideas, plesae?

*** I am learning making android app and I probably just dd something wrong.

I deleted the original purple colors in color.kt so I do not know where that color comes from. I also pur dynamicColor to false in theme.kt

Answer (score 4):

Try removing(or commenting) the following code snippet from the `colorScheme` in your `Theme.kt` file.

```
dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
}
```

It should be like:

```
val colorScheme = when {
    darkTheme -> darkColorScheme
    else -> lightColorScheme
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of places that the connection is being lost. I'll just list a few palces to double check (Some of them you have mentioned already) -

- `md_theme_light_onPrimary` is set to the correct color in Color.kt
- `onPrimaryContainer = md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer,` is assigned in your initialization for `private val LightColors = lightColorScheme()`. Usually in Theme.kt
- `LightColors` is used when initialising your `MaterialTheme()`
- Dynamic color is disabled
- Your composable is wrapped in your theme - `MyTheme{ MyComposable() }`

Also worth noting, that you don't need to specify the `colors` parameter for `Card()` if you're going to use the default color scheme assignments. Generally it's recommended to stick to the defaults to avoid color & contrast mistakes. Card by default uses `surface` for example

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a Material version problem.
Always try to make your testing code **as simple as possible**.
I had a similar problem. I mixed Material with Material3. Removing the library Material from the whole project and change everything to Material3 solved my problem.

To make it simple. I had following code and my color was not applied to the preview (and nowhere else):

```
@Composable
fun ImportExportPageContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello name!",
        modifier = modifier,
        color = MaterialTheme.color.secondary
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    EmptyJetpackComposeTheme {
        ImportExportPageContent()
    }
}
```

The problem was `MaterialTheme.color` is from Material (1.9.0).
I had following implementation for my Theme:

```
@Composable
fun EmptyJetpackComposeTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        darkTheme -> darkColorScheme(
            primary = Red,
            secondary = Green,
            tertiary = Green
        )
        else -> lightColorScheme(
            primary = Red,
            secondary = Green,
            tertiary = Green
        )
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

The class `MaterialTheme` is from `androidx.compose.material3`.
As you see, I set the `colorScheme` property. On the other side (In my Text) I called the `MaterialTheme.color` property.
**Required Change**: Change `MaterialTheme.color` to `MaterialTheme.colorScheme` from Material3.